# Diferença no tempo de execução entre stdio.h e iostream

Tags: c++, runtime

Fiz dois códigos para que um online judge corrigisse. São essencialmente iguais. Mas o com stdio.h é aceito e o com a iostream não, pois excede o tempo limite. Por que isso ocorre?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int tipo[1000000];
int main(){
    int qtdrot, qtdtipos, i, x, min;
    scanf("%d%d", &qtdrot, &qtdtipos);
    for(i=0; i<qtdrot; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &x);
        tipo[x]++;
    }
    min=1000000;
    for(i=1; i<=qtdtipos; i++){
        if(tipo[i]<min)min=tipo[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

O com a iostream:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int tipo[1000000];
int main(){
    int qtdrot, qtdtipos, i, min, t;
    cin>>qtdrot>>qtdtipos;
    for(i=0; i<qtdrot; ++i){
        cin>>t;
        tipo[t]++;
    }
    min=1000000;
    for(i=1; i<=qtdtipos; i++){
        if(tipo[i]<min)min=tipo[i];
    }
    cout<<min<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cin` e `cout` "gastam" uma boa quantidade de tempo sincronizando com os *buffers* do `stdio`. Não é difícil ver programas com operações 3 a 4 vezes mais lentas em comparação ao `scanf` e `printf` (veja [esse exemplo no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12762166/664577)).

Você pode reduzir o tempo de execução desabilitando essa *feature* com o comando:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Adicionalmente o `endl` força um *flush* (veja [essa resposta no Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-cin-cout-slower-than-scanf-printf)). Em *loops* `\n` pode vir a ser mais eficiente (no seu caso, como você só usa `cout` uma vez a diferença não é significativa):

```
cout << min << '\n';
```

Feitas as substituições o exemplo com `iostream` ficou em média 13% mais rápido do que o exemplo com `stdio` na minha máquina / compilador / SO (sempre tenha cuidado generalizando *microbenchmarks*, mas nesse caso a diferença foi notável).